# What is the operation of this RS485 transceiver having this connection?

Tags: circuit-design, rs485, transceiver

I am confuse with the R1 and R2 function. The "Direct Connection" wire is connected to another transceiver's DE/RE.

When the DE/RE is high, driver is enabled, and when the DE/RE is low, the receiver is enabled. However, the DE/RE line here has 2 resistors.

What state is it in?
[image]

Comment: I’d be suspicious of the source of this diagram. The datasheet say logic ‘1’ is >= 2.0V, so if direct connection is 5V, then the chip will see logic ‘1’ on its inputs. R1 should be a lower value methinks.

Comment: depends on what voltage levels the other driver is sending

Answer (score 0):

The resistors are there (most probably) for voltage translation. IC1 is powered with VCC. If direct connection source is powered with a voltage of e.g. two times VCC, then these resistors limit the logic signal voltage to VCC.